# remap keybinding for vim gocode autocomplete feature? (remap keybinding in insert mode)

Tags: key-bindings, autocompletion, insert-mode, filetype-go

So I installed `vim-go` and `gocode` and `Blackrush/vim-gocode.git` (the latter because I use pathogen).

So far so good! I am fine, I can type `<C-x><C-o>` in `insert` mode and I get completion suggestions.

I would like to not only be fine, but really happy. For this, I'd like to see that autocompletion works after pressing just `.` (dot) for example, maybe after a short delay. Or, if that's asking too much, I would like to reduce the `<C-x><C-o>` keybinding to just one, not two, combinations while still being in `insert` mode. For example `<C-Up>`

Can this be done? I am also interested in suggestions for other approaches.

Comment: Note that vim-go already includes `gocode` integration; you don't need to install that `vim-gocode` plugin. `:help vim-go-plugins` lists some plugins that can be used to real-time completion.

Comment: oh nice @MartinTournoij thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I have also looked at deoplete but I haven't managed to install it and get it to work. I don't want to switch to neovim, it says it's possible with vim8 and python3 but I failed following the instructions (which are not very clear to me)